# Only displays one item from array

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I am trying to echo a list of items I gather from an array but it only displays one item when I use this code

```
$sqli = mysqli_query($db_conx, "SELECT url_name FROM provtour ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 10");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqli)) {
$urlname = $row['url_name'];

}
<div><center><?php echo '<a href="etournament.php?n=' . $urlname . '">' . $urlname . '</a>'; ?></center></div>

?>
```

I know the `<center>` should be in css but I am just using it here for test purposes before I move the echoed array into my main style of the website. The above code only echos out one input when there are 7 inside the database.

```
$sqli = mysqli_query($db_conx, "SELECT tourname AND url_name FROM provtour ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 10");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqli)) {
$tourname = $row['tourname'];
$urlname = $row['url_name'];

}
<div><center><?php echo '<a href="etournament.php?n=' . $urlname . '">' . $tourname . '</a>'; ?></center></div>
```

When I use the above code it brings back

```
Notice: Undefined index: url_name in
Notice: Undefined index: tourname in
```

for each row so I have 7 of each errors showing on the page.

```
$sqli = mysqli_query($db_conx, "SELECT * FROM provtour ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 10");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqli)) {
$tourname = $row['tourname'];
$urlname = $row['url_name'];

}
<div><center><?php echo '<a href="etournament.php?n=' . $urlname . '">' . $tourname . '</a>'; ?></center></div>
```

When I use the above code it only echo's out 1 line again.

if anyone could point out where I am going wring with this I would appreciate it very much.

Ideally I would like to gather the `tourname` as well as `url_name`
Thank you.

Comment: Change "SELECT tourname AND url_name FROM provtour" to `SELECT tourname, url_name FROM provtour`

Comment: It brings back one item. Thanks for the comment

Comment: I gave you full reply, how to fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the echo inside `while`:

```
echo '<div><center>';
$sqli = mysqli_query($db_conx, "SELECT * FROM provtour 
     ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 10");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqli)) {
    echo '<a href="etournament.php?n=' . $row['url_name'] . '">' . 
         $row['url_name'] . '</a>';
}
echo '</center></div>';
```

Comment: I cant except your answer as the correct answer yet as I need to wait 4 minutes but I will as soon as it lets me. thanks once again

Comment: @LukeG You probably don't need to assign `$tourname` and `$urlname` as they are used only once, you can just access $row elements directly. `$tourname` is not used at all. I improved the answer a little bit. Maybe, you nee to put tour name as the text of reference instead of url, but that's a minor thing.

Comment: about `$tourname` not being used was an error on my pasting behalves I do need it as I would like the viewer to see the name and now the id. The problem I am now having is I need to look into another table to get tournament id's from the owner so only there items are displayed by the array.

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/GSJrW/ that is the code now. Do not feel like I am asking you to solve this problem as you do not have to. I have just posted it in here so you see what I am trying to do instead of me wondering.

Comment: That echos one line btw

Comment: @LukeG Unfortunately can't look now - have some job to do.

Comment: That is ok as I said I am not asking you to solve it I just shared so you knew what I was trying to do. Thank you for solving my initial problem

Answer (score 1):

In your last example the echo is not in the loop.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I have added plus by it. I will be putting the answer with example as excepted tho as it is providing the right code altho you answer is still correct